# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't see why I would get this, code below:

```
<head>

            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script>
                var json1 = {
                text: "After first paragraph"
                };



                var first_content_added = false;


                $(function() {
                $(".learn-more").on("click", function() {
                $.getJSON("json_info.json", function(data) {
                appendContentToFirstP(data.reviews[0].about.moreinfo);
                });

                });
                });

                function appendContentToFirstP(content) {

                if (first_content_added) {
                return;
                }

                var after_first_p = $('<p class="more-info" />');


                after_first_p.text(content);


                $(".first").append(after_first_p);


                first_content_added = true;
                }


            </script>
</head>
```

What would be causing the error?
My initial thought is the error is because I have not imported JQuery, but I have. It's inside the script tag at the top.

Comment: You don't have included JQuery itself but another librarie jquery.color

Answer (score 5):

You **haven't included jQuery**, you've only included the plugin [jQuery.color](http://code.jquery.com/color/).

Reference it **before** jQuery.color:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. Even when I add this, I get the following three errors as soon as the page loads:

    GET file://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND


    jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


    html.html:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Answer (score 1):

write before that color js like this

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```